# What should my email say when I'm referring someone?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-search, email, referral

What is the correct way to phrase the email when I refer a friend to my organization/to my other friends for a job?

Some people suggested looping in the person who is referred in the CC field in the job referral email, along with a small description about the person being referred, which sounds correct.

This is not an introduction email, but specifically me referring my friend to other people for job openings, where I want to show my friend in good light/highlight his/her strengths.

The receiver **is not a recruiter**, so may not like to be directly contacted from my friend. The target receivers are regular employees, who I hope will check for openings in their organisation.

I want to make the email informative enough so that the receiver gets enough info and interest to actually go through the resume, and also let my friend know that I have actually forwarded her resume at the same time.

Is there a professional/widely accepted etiquette to refer someone I know for jobs in my/friends organization? It'd be great if you can point to any templates for the same!

***Edit :*** 
*Reworded question title and details as per moderator's suggestion.*

Comment: @Draken : I went through the linked question, but that's not exactly what I am looking for. I have added more details in the edit.

Comment: @Draken and the others, please unmark this as a duplicate, as the linked question does not answer this question/specific case. I have provided an explanation in the edit.

Comment: I suggest retitling your question because the title is an exact duplicate and is probably throwing people off. You should shorten this, incorporate the Edit into a single post (we don't need to see an edit history in the post itself) and clarify your core question which is presumably "What should my email say when I'm referring someone?". This is largely company-specific but a general "what should this message say?" is probably answerable.

Comment: Hi @Lilienthal , I have reworded the question and details.

Comment: You have to be careful now as well, as you're currently on the edge of using us as an email writing service, which we generally don't do.

Comment: @Draken, I completely disagree, and there is no need to be patronising. I very well understand what this forum is, and is not. You are not providing constructive input, and are preventing others from doing so too. I have provided my reasoning for the question, if you have no positive input to add, kindly refrain from actions which will prevent others from doing so.

Comment: [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/347028) I'm trying to provide you feedback, however if you're not interested in my feedback, I'll stop. Your question is in the re-open vote queue, so we'll wait and see what the other members think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I usually refer people whom I know by simply mailing their profile details, a reason why I think they would be suitable for the position/role which I am refering them for along with a resume or CV of theirs, to the company's HR or whoever is in charge of hiring.

My mail would look something like this:

> Dear ,
>
> I am forwarding you a profile of Mr/Ms XYZ, for the position of <
>   position >. He/She has x years of experience in the domain, and I
>   think they would be a good fit for the role and the team.
>
> PFA their resume/CV.
>
> regards, ABC

Optionally, I send the email id and/or phone number of the person [with their consent of course], if the contact details are not included in the resume.

Don't cc the person in the email. It is the HR's or the hiring manager's job to reach out to the candidate.

Comment: Keep in mind that if it doesn't work out, they may never take future referrals seriously.

Comment: ^ (+1) Stands true for all referrals

Comment: >if the contact details are not included in the resume.

If those details aren't included then you shouldn't forward it. Resume building 101 says to have all of your contact info at the top. If that rule isn't followed don't attach yourself to this resume.

Comment: Thanks @Dawny33,  this is similar to what I was thinking, and heard from other people. Is this standard etiquette though?

Comment: @bub Yeah. I am following this since 3 years. Got some nice people on board too.  So, this worked in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

I would never refer your friend to the company. By giving the company your friend's information, then you are forever attaching them to you. If they are rude or unprofessional then that will reflect on you and you don't want that unless you REALLY know that friend and their work ethic.

You should refer your company to your friend instead. Say "Hey friend, I just say we have an opening and thought you might want to apply. Here is a link to the posting. Feel free to put me down as somebody you know that already works at the company". This way, the company knows you know each other BUT it is less likely to look bad for you if things don't work out because you didn't directly refer them.

Comment: This really depends on your company. At my company, we have a formal referral policy that includes compensation for the referrer, _but only if_ we go through the official system and attach our name to theirs. That being said, any hiring manager's going to talk to a referrer about the candidate, and saying something like, "I only know them a little, friend of a friend, I just heard they were looking for a job," is perfectly valid.

Comment: My company's policy is to give you cash if they say they know you and they get hired.